# Comparing surround values in a matrix

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I have a problem with radiation mapping in matrices. An MxN matrix is used to record the reading (counts) at each x-y location. If any value is above the threshold then I need to average that value with its surrounding values to establish if it is a true or false positive.

My issue is that I do not know how to treat this problem when I am examining a value on the edge of the matrix. I would assume to start with the average of `A((i-1,j-1),(i-1,j),(i-1,j+1),(i,j-1),...,(i+1,j+1))`. But when there is a value at `(i,j)` on, say, the left edge, there is no `j-1` column.

For example, imagine that the threshold value is `7`.

```
[ 1  4  2;
  3  5  6;
  2  6 10 ]
```

The values to consider then would be `5`, `6`, `6`, and `10`. My initial method would imply zeros outside of the matrix (I believe) and thereby skew the average.

How could I solve this in MATLAB or Python?

Comment: There are several ways to code this up - especially in two languages, Have you tried either e.g. so we can build on one rather than just write code for you?

Comment: You need to decide what boundary conditions (they are called like that) you want to set to your problem. I'd say, in your case, you want to use mirror boundary conditions, or Neumman boundary condition set to zero. Basically repeat the corner value outwards. That way you will not make every corner value an outlier.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB answer

```
threshold = 7;
A = [1 4 2; 3 5 6; 2 6 10];
B = padarray(A,[1,1]);
C = B; %Storing B so that values don't interfere with one another
[x,y] = find(B>=threshold);
for ii1 = 1:length(x)
    for jj1 = 1:length(y)
        ii = x(ii1);
        jj = y(jj1);
        C(ii,jj) = sum(sum(B(ii-1:ii+1,jj-1:jj+1)))./nnz(B(ii-1:ii+1,jj-1:jj+1));
    end
end
A = C(2:end-1,2:end-1);
```

Not the cleanest code but it should get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the help,the padarray and nnz tips were exactly what I needed.